# trying to install sass and getting an error about the webpack

Tags: sass, vuejs3

I am trying to install sass in a Vue project, I'm getting an error so I've tried to --force, even though I was able to see sass-loader in devDependencies when npm run serve I am getting an error about lang="sass", so I decided to npm uninstall sass-loader and node-sass, so I am starting again.
What should I do?
[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKR1x.png)

Answer (score 0):

wasn't to diffucult, because I am using zsh in my terminal I had to wrap in quotation
zsh: npm install -D 'sass-loader@^10' sass

and that's it